# listpicker items are not showing completely

Tags: windows-phone-8

i'm working on a windows phone 8 app, i've implemented a list picker,

here is its code,

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Margin="15,30,30,698" Width="150" Text="Select Category" />
            <toolkit:ListPicker  x:Name="MonthView" Width="270" Margin="-10,10,0,10" SelectionMode="Single" Header="Items" SelectionChanged="ListPicker_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem Content="January" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="February"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="March"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="April"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="May"/>                                        
            </toolkit:ListPicker>


        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

the problem is, it shows blank list, while items are present in it and can be selected,
and 2nd problem is, not more than 5 items can be added,

please suggest me if i'm doing some mistake or any proper solution to show 12 month names in list clearly.

thanks

Comment: Use toolkit:ListPickerItem instead of ListboxItem :D For information, avoid this using to place your components(Big margin is not the correct solution).

Comment: rite said.. i've created it by code, now populating the list items from code but same problem, not more than 5 elements can be placed in listbox...

Comment: When you try with a normal listbox control, you have the same result?